# Center label into form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to center label depending of form width so I do:

```
var formWidth = StatisticsProjectForm.ActiveForm.Width;

   var lblProjectTimeWidth = lblProjectTime.Width;

    lblProjectTime.Width = formWidth / 2 - lblProjectTimeWidth / 2;
```

But when I run program it just don't center to middle of Form, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most answers in the link are wrong!

Comment: why not simply using anchor left + right with text centered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var formWidth = StatisticsProjectForm.ActiveForm.Width;

   var lblProjectTimeWidth = lblProjectTime.Width;

    lblProjectTime.Left = formWidth / 2 - lblProjectTimeWidth / 2;
```

Comment: Also: Don't forget to clear all anchors so the control stays centered even when the form is resized!

Answer (score 1):

use following code for setting label to middle and center of form I used **Label1** and did center to middle of form.

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(centerLabel);
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(centerLabel);
    }
    protected void centerLabel(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Location = new Point((this.Width / 2)-label1.Width, (this.Height / 2)-label1.Height);
    }
```

you also add events for resize and load or whatever you want to do with centerLabel Method.

Comment: Apparently someone upvoted your answer which is wrong. You can not even copy the correct accepted answer. It is *label1.Width / 2* not *label1.Width*, the same with height